# Ensemble Learning and Fusion

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning, fusion

**Question - What is the difference (or are they the same) between ensemble learning and classifier fusion?**

As I understood, ensemble learning is averaging models when making the final prediction, whereas classifier fusion is also the same in meaning. However, when I'm searching for references on ensemble learning, I don't find any mention of the term 'fusion' in some literature. Besides, some references use these two terms (e.g., https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8695622). Any suggestion/resource is appreciated to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search I found the difference: ensemble learning involves training multiple classifiers and combining their predictions, while classifier fusion involves combining the predictions of pre-trained classifiers.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not really mistaken, both are the same.
It's common to read *fusion* as the act of creating an ensemble from a bunch of classifiers - that is the case for the paper you linked.